# What can be said about Radius of Convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

If the following complex series converges for all positive real values of $z$, what can be said about the radius of convergence ? Why ?

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$

Comment: The answer is $\infty$.

Comment: But How ? Nothing is said about other complex values of z. (Sorry for Noob question.)

Comment: If the radius of convergence is a finite number $R$  then the series won't converge at $z=R+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we have the a priori information about power series:

Given any power series, its radius of convergence $R \in [0, \infty]$ is such that the power series

- converges for all $z$ with $|z - z_0| < R$,
- diverges for all $z$ with $|z - z_0| > R.$

---

Now, if the radius $R$ is finite in this case, then we can pick a positive real $z$ outside the the circle $|z - z_0| \le R$ to get a contradiction. For example, note that $z = |z_0| + R + 43$ is one such number.

---

To elaborate: Assume that the radius is $R < \infty$. Then, the number $z = |z_0| + R + 43$ is a positive real and you have $|z - z_0| > R$ and thus, the power series must diverge at $z$ (since it's outside the radius of convergence) but we are given that it converges at $z$ (since $z$ is a positive real number). A contradiction.